# Access application.properties value in thymeleaf template

Tags: thymeleaf

I have one of my spring boot application and inside my application.properties there is one of the property is `url=myurl.net`.
In the same application I have one thyme leaf html template. I wanted to get the url value into that template. I am using the following code inside the thymeleaf html template `<font face=arial size=2 > access the url : </font> ${environment.getProperty(‘url’)}`

Output I am getting :

> access the url : $(environment.getProperty(‘url’)}

Output I am expecting:

> access the url :  myurl.net

Instead of actual value I am getting the same text. Can someone please help me on this. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 44):

You have to use

`${@environment.getProperty('css.specific.name')}` this will fetch `css.specific.name` property from the `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 12):

Map your prop value in your controller, and call it directly from Thymeleaf template.

```java
@Controller
public class XController {

    @Value("${pcn.app.url}")
    private String url;     // Directly instead of using envireonment

    @RequestMapping(value = "form-show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("your-view");

        // The key which will look in your HTML with.
        model.addObject("urlValue", url);
        return model;
    }
}
```

In your html normally call it like this

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <span th:text="#{urlValue}"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I am using email functionality for this requirement not display. ( sending this template to user as email not display ) Email method has mymodel parameter which generated from table . So mymodel is entity class as well as model for email functionality . Either I need to add one variable inside mymodel class or need to find out the way to access directly from application.properties into template with out controller and @value . Please share your thought .

Comment: At the end you’re using some function, and I guess it’s inside some service/component class , so you can use @Value without issue.

Comment: Yes inside service implementation but as I said I need to attach into model sothat I can access inside template . Because we are passing model object into service implementation . Adding variable into model with @javax.persistence.transient is not allowed

Comment: Could you share some code to understand more your case?

Comment: Sorry I can’t . Is there a way to access the value from application.properties into template without this @vlaue .

Comment: it's not the responsibility of the controller to access and pass application scope settings. This is not scalable

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you define settings as data strucutres, and access them through bean scopes

**application.properties**

```
foo.bar=something
```

**Foo.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Foo.class)
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class Foo {
  private String bar;

  public void setBar(String bar) { this.bar = bar; }
  public String getBar() { return bar; }
}
```

**sometemplate.html**

```
...
<span th:text="@foo.getBar()"></span>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using like below

```
@Service("mapService")
public class MapService {

    @Value("${maps.google.api.key}")
    private String googleMapApiKey;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/google/key", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getGoogleMapApiKey() {
        return googleMapApiKey;
    }
}


<script th:src="@{'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?'+'key='+${@mapService.getGoogleMapApiKey()}+'&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete'}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate ways would be define a java class as @Component or @Configuration that will return accessed property using @Value to html template. Difference between them are @Configuration is where you define beans and configurations in a Spring application context and @Component classes are automatically discovered and registered as Spring beans.

```
@Component
public class GetUrl {

    @Value("${base-url}")
    private String url;

    public String getBaseUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

in template you can access it like,

```
th:src="@{${@getUrl.getBaseUrl()} +'/js/basic.js'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

To use value directly from 'application.properties'
like above answers, simple solution would be along with base url, consider surrounding rest of the path both prefix and suffix of url (mostly folder name and file name) as string by surrounding it with single quotes else it will parse "{" into "$%7B@env...".

in template you can access it like,

```
th:src="@{${@environment.getProperty('base-url')}+'/js/basic.js'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it like this, and it works:

```
th:src="@{'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+${@environment.getProperty('google.map.key')}+'&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete'}">
```