# Dynamically pass domain name into an a href link in Spring Jpa

Tags: java, html, spring

I am trying to create a dynamic link in an email which am sending out using Spring Jpa. I created a variable in my application.properties file so that whenever I am pushing to server I can easily change that variable from localhost to the domain name for live deployment. However, when I try to pass the domain name value, the link becomes inactive. I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Here is the application.properties snippet below:

```
server.port=8008

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://41.207.248.189:xxxx/xxx
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****

##GMAIL PROPERTIES
senderEmail = xxxxx
spring.mail.host=xxxx
spring.mail.port=xxx
spring.mail.username=xxxxxx
spring.mail.password=xxxxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=xxxxxxx


domain-name=localhost:4200

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Here is the snippet for the a href I need to pass the domain-name into:

```
 "\n" +

 "<a href='{domain-name}/payments/"+hashlink+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>"+                       

"\n" +
```

This approach above is not working but when I pass the link manually, the "click here" link works:

```
  "<a href='http://127.0.0.1:4200/payments/"+hashlink+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>"+
```

I would appreciate your help. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Below is the html for the email body where I am setting the domain-name

```
            try {
                emailService.sendEmail("PAYMENT NOTIFICATION",

                        "<p>Dear sir/ma,</p>\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "<h4>LETTER OF NOTICE </h4>\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "<p>This is to notify you of the status of your organisation ..... </p>\n" +
                                "<p>You are hereby put on notice to remit the outstanding amount on or before ....</p>\n" +
                                "<p>Kindly follow the link below to make....\n</p>\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "<a href='{domain-name}/payments/"+hashlink+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>"+  
                                "\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "<p>Thank you.</p> \n" +
                                "\n"
                        , org.getEmail());
            } catch (
                    MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Email Service error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps... I look forward to getting a solution. Thanks.

Comment: What template engine are you using to render HTML pages?

Comment: For thymeleaf - look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57620436/607637? Also, you can pass the domainName as Model attribute.

Comment: I am not using thymeleaf, I am using a mimeBodyPart and a mimeMessage to set the email content to html/pdf @gtiwari333

Comment: OK. Can you show us how you are setting the `{domain-name}` parameter to render in HTML? Please provide a full context so that we understand your problem better.

Comment: Ok... Please check the question above, I updated it with the html template for the email where I am setting the {domain-name} .... I appreciate your time @gtiwari333

Comment: ALso show us how you are reading the {domain-name}. And explain what do you mean by `This approach above is not working`? What are you getting when you pass ${domain-name} ?

Comment: I am passing this ... domain-name=localhost:4200 into my application.properties and am trying to read '{domain-name}/payment/"+hashlink+"' as localhost:4200/payment/lVdw2JgMX7AkQ1IUdcZV ... by it is not working, I mean that when I send the email, it doesnt appear as a clickable link anymore but as a text wrapped in <a> tag. When I used ${domain}, I got the same result.

Comment: So you are expecting the `domain-name` from the property file to automatically inject into ` <a href='{domain-name}/payments/"+hashlink+"' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>  ` ?

Comment: You have to properly read the property value using `@Value` eg: `@Value("${domain-name}") String domainName` and use the domainName into your code.

Comment: Read more: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-value-annotations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222040/discussion-between-kingified-and-gtiwari333).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments/discussion here's what you need to do:

1. Read/Inject the property to a String variable using @Value
   `@Value("${domain-name}") String domainName;`
2. Use the variable to construct your href

---

**Full code:**

**application.properties**

`domain-name=www.abc.com`

**DomainNameApp:**

```
package domainname;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DomainNameApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DomainNameApp.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class Ctrl {

    @Value("${domain-name}")
    String domainName; // or use constructor injection

    @GetMapping("a")
    void a() {
        String hashlink = "jsdklfsdklflsdf";
        String html = "<p>" +
                "<a href='" + domainName + "/payments/" + hashlink + "' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>" +
                "</p>";
        System.out.println(html);
    }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your contributions thus far.... when I try this though, it says cannot find method value for ("${domain-name}"} and on the a href line, it says domainName might not have been initialized.

Comment: What's on your application.properties?

Comment: domain-name=localhost:4200

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

Answer (score 1):

Based on answers by @gtiwari333...  I made some corrections to my code. I decided to detail the changes I made for future readers.

First of all, I added http:// to the parameter in my application.properties, as below:

```
domain-name=http://localhost:4200
```

next, I added @Value annotation to the top of my class as below:

```
@Value("${domain-name}")
    String domainName;
```

Then I was able to pass it into the a href link with ease as below:

```
"<p>Kindly follow the link below to make....\n</p>\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "<a href='" +domainName+ "/payments/payment-make" + link + "' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>" +
                                "\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "<p>Thank you.</p> \n" +
                                "\n"
```

Thanks. I give credit to @gtiwari333 for helping me with this.